# Bmp image not correctly loading in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

don't know if anybody ever ran into this error when loading an image in pygame?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SwingyMonkey.py", line 263, in <module>
game = SwingyMonkey()
File "SwingyMonkey.py", line 64, in __init__
self.background_img = pg.image.load('res/jungle-pixel.bmp').convert()
pygame.error: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex() failed
```

let me know if anybody did!!! thanks!!!!!

Comment: A tip: select all code in your question then do Ctrl + K for auto formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to load a file in Mac OSX with a file location that doesn't exist, check that your file location is correct.

If you are running it through a program like NotePad++, the file may exist in that location but NotePad++ runs your program from a different location, so all your relative urls to your image won't work.

So use absolute paths instead of relative ones and see if it works.